# How to add parameters to Linux system call?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel-module

I'm a college student studying OS.

I'm trying to add my own system call in Linux kernel, and I don't understand exactly how to add these parameters into my code.
I want to write only one system call but this call should be inculude these parameters.
Any idea ?

I'll call parameters like this.

```
./systeminfo.out                            > only CPU information
./systeminfo.out -all                       > CPU+system statistics
./systeminfo.out -p 1425                    > CPU+process detail
./systeminfo.out -all -p 1425               > CPU+sys.statistics+ps.detail
```

that is my code(for no parameters)

```
asmlinkage long sys_systeminfo(void)
{

FILE *fPointer;
char singleLine[255];
printk("CPU Information: \n");
if((fPointer=fopen("\\proc\\cpuinfo","r"))!=NULL)
{
int i = 0;  
    while(i<8){

    fgets(singleLine, 50,fPointer);
    puts(singleLine);
    i++;
    }

}
else{
    printk("file not found !");
}



fclose(fPointer);
return 0;
}
```

The sample output should be like that, if two parameters were used:

```
CPU Information:
vendor_id : xx
cpu family : xx
model : xx
model name : xx
Parameter#[process_id]-Process Information:
name: xx
state: xx
uid : xx
pid : xx
ppid : xx
arameter#all-System Statistics:
system was booted since : xx
system has been idle since : xx
the number of active tasks : xx
the total number of processes : xx
```

Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: All of this is already exposed in `/proc`, why add another syscall? And why only a single syscall if you need three different things done? Looks like bad design.

Comment: I am a new learner, and this is my homework.this is a homework given in the third week of the class. And I have no idea what I'm gonna do. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10hTgnx1csZjyw95k-IWr6AocRlYUDKQx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Note assignment asking for new system call + new user program. Your code is using existing /proc - might not meet requirements

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: regarding: `int i = 0;  
    while(i<8){`   This is a very poor code layout.  Suggest using: `for( size_t i=0; i<8; i++ ) {`.   BTW: there is a LOT move involved in writing a function call of an OS than just writing a bit of random code.  Suggest studying a book on the specific OS you are writing for.

Comment: regarding; `puts(singleLine);`  If your writing code for an OS, then the function: `puts()` will not work within the OS.

Comment: regarding: `printk("file not found !");`  This is not the way to post an error message within an OS.  Suggest reading about `syslog()` and related functions

Comment: regarding: `./systeminfo.out`  This looks like a mix of *inx and windows on the command line.  Which OS are you writing for and how does this related to writing a 'new' callable function within the OS?

Comment: regarding: `if((fPointer=fopen("\\proc\\cpuinfo","r"))!=NULL)` coding for windows would use the '\\' however, for linux, use a '/'

Comment: how can use the"-all" in code. is this parameter or flag ?

Comment: "How to add parameters to Linux system call?" - You have `sys_systeminfo` function which is actually a system call. Just make this function to accept parameters. E.g. `asmlinkage long sys_systeminfo(long mode, long pid)`. Responsibility of your `systeminfo.out` *user-space program* could be parsing its string parameters, and calling system call with corresponded arguments.